# Retrieve first element of JSON with php

Tags: php, json

```
I got a JSON from a web site in the raw format:
{"A_B":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000038"},"A_C":{"id":8,"last":"0.00001938"}, ... }
```

How do I get the A_B and A_C??? I do not know what A_B and A_C could be.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
$json = file_get_contents("your json data");
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
    var_dump($key);
}
```

Finally, var_dump($key) displays A_B and A_C.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was it was I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have that raw json in some variable, say `$yourJson`

First, parse your json. `$parsedJson = json_decode($yourJson, true)`

Then run a foreach loop and stop after 2 iterations, You will (hopefully) get the right key-value pair.

```
$i = 0;
$extractedValues = [];
foreach ($parsedJson as $key => $value) {
    $extractedValues[$key] = $value; $i++;
    if ($i === 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, `$extractedValues` contains only two elements found from the first two iterations.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode("Your json variable");
foreach($data as $value){
 echo $value; // here you receive your desire value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = '{"A_B":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000038"},"A_C":{"id":8,"last":"0.00001938"}}';
$dataArray = json_decode($json, true);
$arrayKeys = array_keys($dataArray); // in your case A_B and A_C
```

and if you want to get their values then:

```
foreach($dataArray as $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ": " . $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var $jsonObj = json_decode('{"A_B":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000038"}}')

print $jsonObj->{'A_B'}
```